# Button is not visible because of hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden

I have this HTML code where I have a `div` and a `button`.

Now, with jQuery I made the `div` "hidden" and it will only show when you have selected the correct `<option>`. But now the `button` is only visible if the `div` is too.

HTML:

```
<div id="great">
    Do you like the netherlands?
    <input type="text" id="greatBox" value="Why..."
</div>

<input type="button" id="submitbutton" value="Submit">
```

and the JS/Jquery looks like this

(its spread over the file, the rest is not needed (i guess))

```
$('#great').hide()

$("#selectlist").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() ==  "netherlands") { 
        $('#great').slideDown(750)
        $('#other').hide()
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "other") { 
        $('#great').hide()
    }
});
```

There is not yet any jQuery/javascript bound to the button.

Comment: What you meqan by 'when you have selected the correct " of html".'

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is, but you forgot to close input tag, and here is a jsfiddle of the code http://jsfiddle.net/nimchimpsky/2cUjk/

Comment: The html you posted is missing `#selectlist` and `#other` elements, which you are trying to target in your js.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close `<input type="text" id="greatBox" value="Why..."` `>`

Because it's open the div never gets closed and everything after it will be hidden.

Comment: haha, thank you. had been with this problem for an hour. that something so small. can mess up your code.